# How to diagnose slow NHibernate inserts?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, bulkinsert

I know NHibernate isn't meant to do batch inserts, because it's about 5x slower than SqlBulkCopy, but I decided to use it for code simplicity.

However, my code's not 5x slower. It's 2400x slower. I'm inserting about 2500 records. I've turned off log4net logging. I'm running it in release mode. I'm not using an id generator (I'm specifying it in the code via an integer counter). I'm using a stateless session. I've set a batch size of 100 (I could go more, but doesn't seem to help). I tried adding the generator back in, but setting its class to "assigned".

I'm not inserting any child elements. I've confirmed the batch inserts are occurring.

Is it still calling SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()? But even if it is, that's still a ridiculous amount of time.

I don't do too many batch operations, so I can continue to use SqlBulkCopy for this process, but I'm concerned that my entire application could be running faster.

I don't have a license for NHProf, but I'm wondering if now is the time to download the trial.

I'm using NHibernate 3.3 GA with Syscache2 -- but again, I'm using a stateless session.

Any HBMs, configuration, or code you want to see? Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How much time does it take to insert the 2500 objects?

Comment: Also, could you provide the code that inserts the 2500 objects and the mapping?

Answer (score 2):

> because it's about 5x slower than SqlBulkCopy

You must be joking.

NHibrnate does inserts. Using batched inserts (i.e. more than one insert statement in a command), handwritten - something I do not think NHibernate does - I got around 400 inserts in a specific project.

Using SqlBUlkCopy i got 75000.

That is NOT a factor of 5, that is a factor of of 187.

> However, my code's not 5x slower. It's 2400x slower

Not an NHibernate specialist. Log the connection - I would assume NHibernate sends one insert per batch, which means a LOT of slow processing etc. and is a LOT slower than the stuff I Did (beginning of my text).

Where the heck did you get the 5x factor from? That is a false start to start with.

> I don't do too many batch operations, so I can continue to use SqlBulkCopy for this process, but I'm concerned 
>   that my entire application could be running faster.

Here is a reality check for you: you do not use an ORM when you need extreme select or insert speed. They are there for business rule heavy objects - business objects. When you end up doing bulk inserts or reads, you DO NOT USE A FULL ORM. Simple like that.

When you think SqlBUlkCopy is fast, check this:
* Multiple SqlBulkCopy running on multiple threads...
* ...inerting into temporary tables and then
* ...using one insert into select statement to copy the data to the final table.

Why? Because SqlBulkCopy has some bad locking behavior for multi threads. This is how I got it that high.

AND: 2500 rows is low for SqlBulkCopy - the setup overhead is significant (i.e. before line 1).... So you will get less gain. I use 50k row batches.

What is NHibernate doing on the wire level?

> I've confirmed the batch inserts are occurring.

How? What do you consider a batch insert?

Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: here are some numbers: http://ayende.com/blog/4137/nhibernate-perf-tricks  even if he is one magnitude better than real the difference is factor 30 not 187.

Comment: For me it is ;) Point mostly being that the last 2 years I did ETL load reoutines mostly, and performance there is super critical.... so I am quite good in that part by now.

Comment: dito. i mainly worked in datamigrations where going the sql route would mean cryptic column names and compositeId references en masse. tuned NHibernate was never that many magnitudes slower like you have shown here. waiting 3 hours instead of 45 minutes but save 1 month work implementing the etl was well worth it.

Comment: @Firo, that's the link I used when making the 5x claim. SqlBulkCopy for 2500 rows is overkill, but when it takes NHibernate in a stateless session 3 minutes to insert the records, I have to do something, SqlBulkCopy took 77ms. I know it's doing a batch because if I turn on log4net and SQL logging, I can see the batches. I understand the trade-offs of using ORMs, but if I've poorly configured or implemented the ORM, that's not the ORMs fault. There are no triggers on the table. I think 3 minutes for 2500 records is excessive -- 13 inserts per second. I just don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Agree. Even with non batching and individual transactions, 13 would be kind of low for a desktop. This is beyond slow.

Answer (score 0):

inserting 10000 objects with a couple long and string properties into a local mysql database on my devmashine takes:

```
StatelessSession:  4,6 seconds
Session:           5,7 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found if you are doing many inserts the First Level Cache will clog and soon cause it to slow down to a crawl. You can try and use a stateless session or just open and close the Session periodically, ie every 5 inserts. You will of course lose things like transactions by closing session.

But ultimately, I tend to use SqlBulkCopy if I have more than about 100 rows to insert, many times quicker.

Comment: session.Clear() will also clean the cache but holds the transaction open